# Custom Download Manager IWebbrowser2

Tags: c++, com, wxwidgets, iwebbrowser2

Sorry if my question is previously answered here but I have, for days, searched the internet including SO with no solution.

Basically I want to Implement Download Manager for IE webbrowser control (Not IDE itself).
I have read a lot on MSDN and among them is [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which shows how to create it.
The Problem with this example (and my problem in that case) is where do I register/apply the IServiceProvider to my web browser. The Article does not say. However searching I found [this question](http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.vc.atl/2006-02/00064/Re-How-To-Implement-IServiceProvider-and-IDownloadManager.html) and it say I quote

> Use CAxWindow::QueryHost to get IObjectWithSite pointer. Call SetSite 
>   passing your IServiceProvider implementation.

Unfortunately I don't use or know anything about ATL as I use wxWidgets. So where do I get that in wxWebview or "vanilla" MS COM?

here is what I have so far

```
HRESULT wxDownloadMgr::Download(IMoniker *pmk, IBindCtx *pbc,DWORD dwBindVerb,  
                  LONG grfBINDF,BINDINFO *pBindInfo, LPCOLESTR pszHeaders,LPCOLESTR pszRedir,UINT uiCP )
{
    // Get URL
    LPOLESTR urlToFile;
    HRESULT result = pmk->GetDisplayName( pbc, NULL, &urlToFile ); 
    //OLECHAR is simply a wchar_t and an LPOLESTR is a wide character string (e.g. wchar_t*). 
    wxString url(urlToFile);
    wxWebViewEvent event(wxEVT_COMMAND_WEB_VIEW_DOWNLOAD_BEGINS,GetId(), url, ""); 
    event.SetEventObject(this);//WHICH OBJECT TO SET HERE????????
    HandleWindowEvent(event);

    ::MessageBox(NULL,"Download","Download Manager",MB_OK);
    return S_OK;
} 

STDMETHODIMP wxServiceProvider::QueryService(REFGUID guidService,
                                            REFIID riid,
                                            void **ppv)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_NOINTERFACE;

    if (guidService == SID_SDownloadManager && riid == IID_IDownloadManager)
    {
        // Create new DownloadMgr object using ATL.
        CComObject<wxDownloadMgr>* pDownloadMgr;
        hr = CComObject<wxDownloadMgr>::CreateInstance(&pDownloadMgr);

        // Query the new CDownloadMgr object for IDownloadManager interface.
        hr = pDownloadMgr->QueryInterface(IID_IDownloadManager, ppv);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override wxActiveXContainer::QueryClientSiteInterface to add your own interface implementation like IServiceProvider or IDocHostUIHandler to the client site. An example can be found in the [wxIEContainer](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13784#comment:1) class.

Comment: Do you mean
bool wxIEContainer::QueryClientSiteInterface(REFIID iid, void **_interface,
                                             const char *&desc)
{
    if (m_uiHandler && IsEqualIID(iid, wxIID_IDocHostUIHandler))
    {
        *_interface = (IUnknown *) (wxIDocHostUIHandler *) m_uiHandler;
        desc = "IDocHostUIHandler";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: Yes that is an example of how to extend wxActiveXContainer

Comment: You mean I do something like theis: http://pastebin.com/AekYv70N
Or Should I create new wxServiceProvider and assign its pointer to m_uiHandler? Currently I have just duplicated and modified the code there

Comment: you would write your own wxActiveXContainer like wxIEContainer does -or just derive form wxIEContainer and override QueryClientSiteInterface. Note you need to actually return the correct interface in QueryClientSiteInterface, you can't return an IDocHostUIHandler when the webbrowser control asks for IServiceProvider

Comment: I Just copied the code in wxWebview and added check for IServiceProvider that is 
else if (m_uiHandler && IsEqualIID(iid, wxIID_ISERVICEPROVIDER))

So when I have done this is that all that I need to do to make custom download work? I need to sleep now it is quiet late night here!

Comment: you need something that implements IServiceProvider to return, like m_serviceProvider.